# Best way to replace a single view from an imported module

Tags: django

The use case in question is replacing the "checkout_steps" view in cartridge, but should be general to any case.  What is the best way to do this?

My thought was to put a specific url earlier in my master url pattern-

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^shop/checkout', myapp.myview),
    url(r'^shop/', include(cartridge.shop)),
)
```

Will this work?  Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: but if you change the order in your tuple, the second one will never match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work, as [Django stops looking after the first match](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request).

But a better solution would be to move that view under cartridge app views.py file because it logically is under the same path and it is an exception right now (of course you can only do that if you have written cartridge app :)).